# Тире или запятая перед "это"?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

**Решение отказаться от членства в РАН «унизит не только самого избранного в ряды академии человека () это унизит всю академию», считает член Совета Российского фонда фундаментальных исследований, академик Юрий Балеги.**

Перед "это" ставится тире или запятая?
Влияет ли на постановку знака цитирование?

Comment: По-моему, здесь должны стоять и запятая, и тире

Answer (score 3):

Решение отказаться от членства в РАН «унизит не только самого избранного в ряды академии человека ―  это унизит всю академию», считает член Совета Российского фонда фундаментальных исследований, академик Юрий Балеги.

Это БСП, возможна постановка **запятой** (значение распространения) или **тире** (значение противопоставления при наличии паузы).

В кавычки пи цитировании заключается **дословное высказывание**, поэтому знаки препинания должны **соответствовать** источнику.

Кстати, в Сети есть  запись этого высказывания с другим оформлением:

По мнению Балеги, если же кто-то из госслужащих решит отказаться от членства в академии, то это «унизит **не только** самого избранного в ряды академии человека, **но** унизит всю академию».

Comment: А в чем здесь противопоставление?

Comment: Только избранный академик  или  вся академия.

Comment: @Sibylla, в этой фразе меня смущает другая запятая, перед словом "академик". По-моему, это неоднородные определения (академик - звание, член Совета - должность). Помогите разобраться

Comment: Вот как считает Розенталь (и Лопатин тоже): заведующий кафедрой профессор Г. В. Степанов; начальник лаборатории кандидат химических наук В. К. Леонова. И вот как они пишут: "И все же для большинства людей госслужба и научная деятельность несовместимы, считает директор Института космических исследований РАН, академик РАН Лев Зеленый".http://www.oilru.com/news/544008  По правилу это неоднородные приложения (должность и ученое звание), правила эти действующие, но не слишком популярные.

Comment: Не очень-то хочется разбираться в должностях и званиях, вопрос не кажется принципиальным и т.д. Так что формально правило действует, а фактически не всегда соблюдается.

Answer (score 0):

Ставится запятая, поскольку идёт перечисление последствий, а не описание.

Comment: Наличие «не только» говорит не в пользу перечисления.